# substring(0,4) on jquery html giving null

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring, substr

### This is my code:

```
var revista = $('#revistas_esp_1 option:selected').html();          
var myname = revista.substring(1,3);
console.log(myname);
console.log(revista);
```

gets the html alright, but myname shows empty.

I have tried with substr aswell, same result. I don't get any error, just an empty log. I also have tried to use text() instead of html().

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(revista);` ?

Comment: can you post your html code too

Comment: Are you sure that it's trimmed? There may be whitespace around it.

Comment: The output of console.log(revista); is: R172 - abril 2012

Comment: And btw: `substr()` (mentioned in the title) is not the same as `substring()` (mentioned in the posting).

Comment: it does work for me, are you sure you don't get anything?

Comment: `substring` works fine - proof ["R172 - abril 2012".substring(1,4)](http://jsfiddle.net/uWwUF/)

Comment: Seem to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Cc2PK/. Must be something else.

Comment: OYes, I have a ton of whitespace, I have just realized pasting the code :P I am generating the ul through php, I just need to place the php tags differently, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ok, confirmation, it works now!

Comment: Just a tip : when logging string data to the console I always make sure that the string size is visibile eg console.log ('myname =' + myname + '.').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a blank space issue, it got solved putting the indenting space in the php and not in the HTML.